# Problem comparing fields with web2py in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I have this model in web2py DAL:

```
db.define_table('category',
     Field('name','string'),
     format='%(name)s'
)

db.define_table('uploaded_question',
    Field('text','string'),
    ...
    Field('category', 'string')    
)
```

This:

```
db.category(db.category.name == uploaded_question.category) always
```

returns none in GAE sandbox (it works fine in SQLlite).

How should I adapt this sentence to work in GAE?

Comment: I think Field('category', 'string') should be Field('category', db.category)

Comment: In this case rows = db(db.category.id == db.uploaded_question.category).select()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell from the partial code but it seems you are doing two things:
1) you are denormalizing (db.uploaded_question.category is a string and not a reference)
2) you are doing an inner JOIN (even if category is not a reference). Your syntax is incorrect should be

```
   rows = db(db.category.name == db.uploaded_question.category).select()
```

The problem is that that you cannot do JOINs on GAE. They do not support joins.

Anyway, it not clear why you do a join if you have denormalized, so perhaps I misunderstood.

We will be happy to help you more on the web2py mailing list.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! I am in web2py now